# Array only values in keys numeric order

Tags: php

I've an array like this:

```
8:16, 9:8, 10:11, 11:5, 12:5, 13:13, 14:42
```

and I want it to be:

```
0:16, 1:8, 2:11 ....
```

in PHP.

I know I can do an own function. but I think it should be one built in.

I've tried: array_values

Comment: Did you try [natsort](http://php.net/natsort)?

Comment: array_values() should work mate

Comment: [It should work](http://codepad.viper-7.com/Ycvkqk).

Comment: You mean you want to subtract the lowest integer part (8) from each value?

Comment: Ahhh, now i got it. You don't want to sort, the part before the : is you array key. Then `array_values()` is absolutely correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this function should do the trick:

```
$array = array_values($array);
```

see: http://php.net/array_values

Answer (score 1):

Please try this i think  its your exact requirement.

```
$arr = array('8:16', '9:8','10:11');

$i=0;
foreach($arr as $val){

    $arr1 = explode(':',$val);
    $arr2[] = $i.":".$arr1[1];
    $i++;
}
print_r($arr2);
```

Comment: good point, I think everyone has assumed `0:1, 1:2` was pseudo for `array(1,2)` - never considered OP meant literally.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `natsort()`

[Documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.natsort.php)

Comment: doesn't answer the question mate - he's not asking for the array to be sorted (though the title is misleading), he's asking for the existing values to be numerical/zero-indexed.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
array_values($yourArray);
```

I think it should work properly.

Answer (score 0):

I think @Praveenkalal sussed what you meant, but I'll just add another alternative:

```
$i = 0;
array_walk($array, function(&$v) use(&$i) {
  $v = preg_replace('/\d+:(\d+)/', ($i++).':$1', $v);
});
```

[run code](http://ideone.com/qaOIah)

Alternatively, if you're array is already zero-indexed like we have assumed this will work:

```
foreach($array as $key => &$val)
  $val = preg_replace('/\d+:(\d+)/', $key.':$1', $val);
```

[run code](http://ideone.com/kSjAA6)

---

arrays... fun fun fun

Just to clarify - there's no built-in function because what you are doing is too specific - if your array values are key:value pairs then normally you'd have mapped them to an array as such - which is why we all thought [`array_values`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php) would be sufficient.

For example if your data was in a format like:

```
$array = array(
  8  => 16, 
  9  => 8, 
  10 => 11,
 ...
);
```

you'd have the full range of php's internal functionality available to you.